# QGIS Print Composer's "Render as HTML" not outputing what is input

Tags: qgis, print-composer, html

Am I not using the correct version of HTML letter spacing?

In Print Composer using a Label with "Render as HTML" checked, I input 

for what looks good in Print Composer only to have the output PDF have the text extending off the page.

I have tried many variations in the settings and have isolated it to `<span style="letter-spacing:.1em;">` causing the issue.

The full code of the title block here:

```
<span style="letter-spacing:.1em;"><p style="line-height:1.80"><b>FIGURE 4 <br>
<span style="font-size:10pt">National Wetland Inventory Map<br>
General Aviation Avenue Tract<br>
Austin, Texas</b></span></p></span>
```

All of it works fine except `<span style="letter-spacing:.1em;">`

Have also tried `<div style="line-height:.1em;">` and see the same over shooting the page on PDF output issue.

Screen shots: [image]

Comment: Decrease font size, ;-)

Comment: I changed the parent font size to 6, then bumped the html font size up and that made it fit. A good enough work around but this seems like a bug that needs fixing. Or if they just added the "Spacing" options for "letter" and "word" like in the Layer Properties > Labels > Text.